# org.apache.spark.SparkException:Failed to get broadcast_25_piece0 of broadcast_25 when try to read broadcast variable updated at regular interval

Tags: java, apache-spark, spark-streaming, sparkcore

I am running spark streaming application which process real time events received from kafka.

I am using org.apache.spark.streaming.util.RecurringTimer which runs code at say every 10 seconds which is responsible for building java object say CollegeInfo and broadcast it.

below is the code which runs every 10 second and broadcast the collegeInfo object

```
class JavaObjectBroadCastTimerFun extends AbstractFunction1<Object, BoxedUnit> implements Serializable
        {

            Broadcast<CollegeInfo> broadCastVariable = null;

            public BoxedUnit apply(Object s)
            {
                CollegeInfo collInfo = new CollegeInfo();
                collInfo.setUniversityName("university");
                collInfo.setCollegeName("college");
                collInfo.setCollegeCode("1");

                broadCastVariable = sc.broadcast(collInfo);

                return null;
            }
        };
```

There is a code which runs on executor node when it receives event and access the broadcast variable.

```
JavaObjectBroadCastTimerFun javaObjectBroadCastTimerFun = new JavaObjectBroadCastTimerFun();

        if (javaObjectBroadCastTimerFun.broadCastVariable != null
            && javaObjectBroadCastTimerFun.broadCastVariable.value() != null)
        {
            CollegeInfo coll = javaObjectBroadCastTimerFun.broadCastVariable.value();
            System.out.println(coll.toString());
        }
```

Expectation is i should be able to get broadcasted college info every time i read the broadcast variable value.
But some times i am receiving below Spark exception

```
rg.apache.spark.SparkException: Failed to get broadcast_25_piece0 of broadcast_25
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1$$anonfun$2.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:138)
at scala.Option.getOrElse(Option.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply$mcVI$sp(TorrentBroadcast.scala:137)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
at scala.collection.immutable.List.foreach(List.scala:318)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.org$apache$spark$broadcast$TorrentBroadcast$$readBlocks(TorrentBroadcast.scala:120)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast$$anonfun$readBroadcastBlock$1.apply(TorrentBroadcast.scala:175)
at org.apache.spark.util.Utils$.tryOrIOException(Utils.scala:1198)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.readBroadcastBlock(TorrentBroadcast.scala:165)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value$lzycompute(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast._value(TorrentBroadcast.scala:64)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.TorrentBroadcast.getValue(TorrentBroadcast.scala:88)
at org.apache.spark.broadcast.Broadcast.value(Broadcast.scala:70)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:330)
at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDDLike$$anonfun$foreach$1.apply(JavaRDDLike.scala:330)
at scala.collection.Iterator$class.foreach(Iterator.scala:727)
at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.foreach(InterruptibleIterator.scala:28)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:928)
at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD$$anonfun$foreach$1$$anonfun$apply$28.apply(RDD.scala:928)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1883)
at org.apache.spark.SparkContext$$anonfun$runJob$5.apply(SparkContext.scala:1883)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ResultTask.runTask(ResultTask.scala:68)
at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:90)
at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:229)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I am using spark 1.5.1.
I tried to use to set `spark.broadcast.factory=org.apache.spark.broadcast.HttpBroadcastFactory` but it did not work
Can please tell me the reason for this exception and is my code correct to broadcast variables at regular interval.
Early reply is highly appreciated

Thanks in advance